# Class DefaultGraphTraversal<S,E> what is the class purpose? and what are S and E classes represent?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Couldn't figure from the documentation and the source code what do they  represent?

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.5/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/DefaultGraphTraversal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache TinkerPop/Gremlin a Traversal is analogous to a query and a query can return more than just vertices.

`<S,E>` are type variables that form the [Java generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) definition for the `DefaultGraphTraversal` class. They aren't specific classes, but represent the "start" (for `S`) and "end" (for `E`) types that will go into and come out of the traversal respectively. In a sense, those types become defined when you form the traversal you want to execute. `g.V().count()` returns a `GraphTraversal<Vertex,Long>` where the `S` is defined as `Vertex` and the `E` is defined as a `Long` - the start to the traversal is a `Vertex` and the end to the traversal is a `Long`.

Comment: Thanks @stephen mallette for the answer. I do know what Java Generics are, I can see why it was confusing so I've updated the question.
I'm still confused about the meaning of the Traversal concept, according to wikipedia - _graph traversal refers to the process of visiting each vertex in a graph._ I can see why you need a "start" class , but why the "end" class is from different type? isn't the end mean the last vertex in the traversal?

Comment: In Apache TinkerPop/Gremlin a `Traversal` is analogous to a query and a query can return more than just vertices. So `GraphTraversal<Vertex,Long>` for `g.V().count()` starts with vertices from the graph but ultimately the output will be a `Long` value because you want a `count()` of those vertices. Think of the `E` as the output of the query.

Comment: thanks again @stephen mallette, the last comment really clarify some things for me.